# avs2avi stripping audio channel?

Tags: avisynth

I'm trying to build a video using a command line wizard I've written. To do this, I am constructing an AVISynth file (in this case, a huge 1,820-line, 94Kb file) and use `avs2avi` to render it.

It works great, but for some reason it doesn't save the audio.

Here's the general layout of my AVS:

```
# lots of code to generate the video here
vid = titles+main+ending
aud = WAVSource("render.wav")
AudioDub(vid,aud)
```

It plays fine in Media Player, audio and all. But with this command line:

```
avs2avi render.avs render.avi -c XVID
```

It renders the video without any sound. Similarly, if I drop the `-c XVID` parameter, I get the dialog asking me for a compression format and I still get no sound.

What gives, and how can I fix this? The only alternative I'm seeing is using something like VirtualDub to put the audio track back in, but it seems like a hassle.

---

Edit: It doesn't work with simple scripts either.

```
BlankClip(length=100,width=256,height=256,fps=25).AudioDub(WAVSource("beep.wav"))
```

Produces sound in Media Player, and a silent video through `avs2avi`.

Comment: Does it work with just a really simple `AudioDub`? (i.e. no previous video generation)

Comment: No, it does not. See edit.

Comment: I was about to comment that avs2avi does not do audio. But now I came across [this](http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-36768.html) doom9 thread and I'm not so sure. 'int 21h' is one of the authors, have a look at the thread if you like.